# Какой библиотекой реализовать подсистему конфига для кластера ПО, запущенного на нескольких ПК?

Tags: c++, поиск-библиотек, configuration, cluster

Задача: реализовать подсистему конфига для кластера ПО, запущенного на нескольких ПК.

Требования:

- изменения в конфигураторе на одной ноде нужно реплицировать на все остальные
- возможность устанавливать обработчики на изменение значений в конфиге

Есть ли подходящие под задачу библиотеки?

**Update #0**

По определенным причинам нужна именно встраиваемая в ПО библиотека, а не отдельное приложение.

**Update #1**

Целевые OS: Windows, Linux

**Update #2**

После долгого испытания различных вариантов было принято решение писать свою внутреннюю библиотеку.

На данном этапе в качестве основы взяты `RocksDB` как движок БД и `gRPC` для сети.

**Update #3**

Наткнулся на заброшенный проект https://github.com/pinterest/rocksplicator

Из минусов - слишком много зависимостей.

**Update #4**
Кажется нашел аналогию, подходящую нашей системе:

мы создаем софт, чем то напоминающий систему управления "умным домом".

При этом пользователи не являются знатоками в администрировании.

Comment: Тут дело не в либе а в дизайне - Вам нужен сервис на который будут подписываться Ваши апликейшены и после изменения централизованного конфига на этом сервисе будет посылаться нотифай всем апликейшенам и они начтут выгрузку новых конфигов и делать дальше что нужно, как минимальный пример - подписка в постгре на нотифай

Comment: посмотрите в сторону zookeeper

Comment: Это умеют etcd, consul, zookeper https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3/learning/why/